# My javascript variable changes when the associated observable changes

Tags: knockout.js

I am learning Knockout and would like to understand something. I have the following code:

```
var vehicleModel = { "VehicleId": 0, "Category": "", "Brand": "", "Model": "", "Registration": "", "Available": "" };
self.searchCriteria = ko.observable(vehicleModel);
```

If I understand, the value of vehicleModel is affected to self.searchCriteria, right? And this searchCriteria will be 'observable' and so accessible in my view, right?

What I don't understand is that when I change values from searchCriteria in my view, then values of vehicleModel is also changed.

Does anybody can explain me?

Comment: The observable for `searchCriteria` is probably getting a reference to `vehicleModel` instead of a new copy, so changing one will change the other, just like any other instance of using object references. Does changing a value in `vehicleModel` affect the values in `searchCriteria`?

Comment: To respond to your question: yes. Now how can I have only a 'copy' without changing the initial values of vehicleModel? Thanks.

Comment: Give this a try: `self.searchCriteria = ko.observable(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vehicleModel)));` This first creates a json string out of your object, then parses it into a new object, and passes it into the observable.

Comment: You're welcome. And I agree, it is tricky. It would be nice if JavaScript had a simple, straightforward way to get a new copy of an object.

Comment: you can also use ko.toJS(vehicleModel) instead of parse and stringify.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change your vehicleModel to:

```
var vehicleModel = function(){
    this.VehicleId=0;
    this.Category="";
    this.Brand="";
    this.Model="";
    this.Resgitration="";
    this.Available="";
}
```

And then do:

```
self.searchCriteria = ko.observable(new vehicleModel());
```

In this way, vehicleModel is like a class and you are instantiating a new object every time you do: new vehicleModel()